# Spring - Auth: How to replace HTML authentification failure page with JSON-Response

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I have two spring boot services.

1. The frist one is an AuthServer (@EnableAuthorizationServer)
2. The secoind one is a ResourceServer (@EnableResourceServer)

When I call a method of the REST interface of the ResourceServer, without sending a valid token I get the following error in Postman:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        b {
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        a {
            color: black;
        }

        .line {
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #525D76;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

An Error-HTML-Page...but I would prefer something like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-19T08:59:06.002+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Invalid Token",
    "message": "Plz use a valid token",
    "path": "/rest/portfolio/2"
}
```

How can I set my custom auth-failure response? Do I have to do that in the AuthServer-Service or at the ResourceServer?

If I send no Authoriation-Header at all I get

```
<UnauthorizedException>
    <error>unauthorized</error>
    <error_description>Vollständige Authentifikation wird benötigt um auf diese Resource zuzugreifen</error_description>
</UnauthorizedException>
```

I would prefer to replace this with a custom message too.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your own `Authentication Entry Point` and configure it in `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter -> (HttpSecurity http)` like

```
...
.and()
.exceptionHandling()
.authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
...
```

Sample Auth Entry Point:

```
/**
 * Returns a 401 error code (Unauthorized) to the client.
 */
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Autowired
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper;

    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {

           Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = new HashMap<>();
           jsonReponse.put("status", false);
           
           /*Put everything else into this map or better you can have a class       to hold your response and initialise that here */
          
          response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
          response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
          objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), responseJson);     
    }
}
```